# google adwords api oauth2 api having error with refresh token

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I'm trying to connect with google adwords account on behalf of my client using a custom made WP plugin using oauth2 api.

While using it first time Its generating auth token and refresh token and I'm storing it in DB. But after sometime Auth token expires So I'm generating it again using refresh token using this code.

```
$oauth2->setCode($_GET['code']);
$authCode = $_GET['code'];
$authToken = $oauth2->fetchAuthToken();
print_r( $authToken );
```

But its giving me error of "Missing authorization code".

Comment: did you have a value in : $_GET['code']

Comment: yes i have value there